# javascript onclick cancel focus

Tags: javascript, onclick, confirm

i make return confirm  in from action post method..  Code is working but i need to focus Cancel when confirm is come. But Always ok is focused. How i solve that issue

my code is below..

*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation() {
var consumption = document.getElementById("consumption").value;
var texthere1 = document.getElementById("texthere1").value;
var line = document.getElementById("texthere").value;
return confirm("You are about to issue Material <?php echo ltrim($data , "0") ;  ?> from 2100/<?php echo ($data2 ) ;  ?> To a Dying STO " + texthere1 + " At line " + line + " of " + consumption + " KG. Are You Sure ?")   ;  
return false;   
}
</script>
<form action="a.php" method="post">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return confirmation()">
</form>
```

*

Comment: I think you can not have control on this you can use modalpopup insted and focus it

Comment: You can't change the default behavior of the browser-generated dialog. You can create your own confirm dialog using js and css.

Answer (score 0):

**When confirm is come using this**

```
document.getElementById('id').blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no possibility to do that, see this similar post: [JavaScript: How to select "Cancel" by default in confirm box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699582/javascript-how-to-select-cancel-by-default-in-confirm-box).